# Changes Brushes.Color by a variable?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, brush

pSo, how exactly would i go about changes which Brushes.Color a method uses?
say we set a variable to black via console input, and then change it to red? how would i do this in my code, i have color capitalized to note where and what i want changed in the method.

```
graphics.DrawString(cmd.AllArguments, arialFont, Brushes.COLOR, secondLocation);
```

Answer (score 4):

Declare a variable of type Color, say:

```
private Color foreColor;
```

Then you simply create a brush for that color:

```
using (var brush = new SolidBrush(foreColor)) {
    graphics.DrawString(cmd.AllArguments, arialFont, brush, secondLocation);
}
```

Best way to convert a color from a string is by using the ColorConverter class, same one that's used in the Properties window:

```
foreColor = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConverFrom(str);
```

Comment: how would i convert a string to set foreColor?